# NULL Value Getting Inserted from .NET into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add `EmpID` from a .NET application into SQL Server. The .NET application has a combo box of employee names, but I need to insert `Empid` into the table. My application ends up with adding `NULL`, even when the combobox value is not.

```
private void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string str = "";

        if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (str == "")
                {
                    str = checkedListBox2.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    str += "," + checkedListBox2.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                    // com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillid", str);
                }
            }

            con.Open();

            string query = "execute usp_Skill_level_update_dotnet @id,@skillid,@levelid";

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            // com.Parameters.Clear();                   
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Associate.SelectedValue ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillid", str);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@levelid", SkillLevel.SelectedValue);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("done");

            while (checkedListBox2.CheckedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
                checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox2.CheckedIndices[0], false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select at least one skill");
        }
    }
}


enter code here
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Skill_Level_Update_Dotnet]
(
@Id int,
@SkillID nvarchar(100),
@LevelId int
)
as begin


Insert into Skill_Temp (id,SkillID,Levelid) values (@id,@Skillid,@levelid)

END
```

Above is the Procedure that i m trying to call.

Comment: Have added Associate.ValueMember = "EmpID";
            Associate.DisplayMember = "EmpName";
in the ComboBox Load Method.

Comment: Can you show `usp_Skill_level_update_dotnet`?

Comment: Using `AddWithValue` can lead to surprising and unexpected results, especially with your `?? DBNull.Value`. Try defining your SqlParameters explicitly. ref: [Using parameters with a SqlCommand and a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#using-parameters-with-a-sqlcommand-and-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: @FrankNielsen added to my code, also the table skill_temp in SP was created as 
Create table Skill_temp 
(id int foreign key references tbl_emp(empid),
Skillid nvarchar(100),
Levelid int foreign key references tbl_Skill_level(levelid)
)

Comment: Try hardcode an `Id` that exists on  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 42 );` and see what happens. (replace 42 with a valid id number). If that is working, `Associate.SelectedValue` must be null even through you see something else...

Comment: Thanks @FrankNielsen, Identified there was some problem with my Employee Class.